# Use German dictionary and language model with Sphinx4

Tags: cmusphinx, sphinx4

I can use the en-us things that come with Sphinx4, no problem:

```
cfg.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us")
cfg.setDictionaryPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict")
cfg.setLanguageModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin")
```

I can use this to transcribe an English sound file recording.

Now I want to use this with **German** recordings. On the website I find a link to [Acoustic and Language Models](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/). In it there is an archive 'German Voxforge'. It it I find the corresponding files for the **acoustic model** path. But it does not contain a dictionary or language model as far as I can see.

How do I get the **dictionary and language model** path for German in Sphinx4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create them yourself. You can create language model from subtitles or wikipedia dumps. The documentation is [here](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm).

Latest German models are actually not on CMUSphinx page, they are at [github/gooofy](https://github.com/gooofy/voxforge). In this gooofy project you can find dictionary documentation, models and related matherials.

Comment: Sorry. To clarify. From the downloads from gooofy, I am supposed to use `voxforge.dic` (26K words while the en-us has 134K) and `voxforge.lm.DMP`, right?

Comment: Yes, they work. The file ending must be changed to lower-case `.dmp` because Sphinx4 only recognises lower-case extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the German model with **pocketsphinx** and got some errors due to the "invalid" language model *.lm.**bin** files were used.
I have switched to the *.lm.**gz** and it working fine.

The proper configuration list is:

- **fst** = voxforge-de.fst
- **hmm folder** =  model_parameters/voxforge.cd_cont_6000
- **dictionary** =  cmusphinx-voxforge-de.dic
- **language model** =  **cmusphinx-voxforge-de.lm.gz**

To get the "hmm" path you should unzip an archive:
cmusphinx-de-voxforge-5.2.tar.gz

I think it should be the same for a Sphinx4, so please give it a try.